# When I submit the form the values not inserting in razor engine mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Below is my view page. without `<form>` tag when I insert the values, its perfectly inserting. But when I insert with `<form>` tag the values not inserting, the debug point pointing to `[HttpGet]` instead of `[HttpPost]`.   For validation purpose I have inserted the `<form>` tag. But it seem to be no use.. Tell me the solution....

```
@model CustMaster.Models.MyAccount
@using CustMaster.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Information";
}    

<html>
<head>
   <title>Customer Information</title>
   <link href="../../style.css" rel="stylesheet">     
</head>
<body>

<form action="" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal">

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {        
      <table>
        <tr>
           <td><h3>User Information</h3></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
             <div class="control-group">

               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerFirstName, 
               new { @class = "control-label" })

                <div class="controls">
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerFirstName, 
                   new { @class = "input-xlarge" })

                </div> 
             </div>
           </td>

          <td>
             <div class="control-group"> 

               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerMiddleName, 
               new { @class = "control-label" })

                <div class="controls">
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerMiddleName, 
                     new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
                </div>
             </div>
         </td>
      </tr>     
 </table>
 <button type="submit">Register</button>
}
@*</form>*@

   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>   
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>   
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>   
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../script.js"></script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Below is my Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyAccount myacc)
{
   MyAccount ma = new MyAccount();
   var objview = ma.GetCustInfo(myacc);
   return View();            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest html forms => it results in invalid markup and undefined behavior. You will have to remove the outer `<form>`. The `Html.BeginForm` already generates a form tag. You seem to have commented the closing form tag but not the opening.

And please format your code a little. It's a complete mess to read:

```
@model CustMaster.Models.MyAccount
@using CustMaster.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Information";
}

<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer Information</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/style.css")" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contact-form" })) 
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><h3>User Information</h3></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="control-group">
                       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerFirstName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                       <div class="controls">
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerFirstName, new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
                       </div> 
                   </div>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <div class="control-group">
                       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerMiddleName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                       <div class="controls">
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerMiddleName, new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>

       <button type="submit">Register</button>
    }

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/js/jquery.validate.js")"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/script.js")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also please notice that I have fixed your script references by introducing url helpers instead of hardcoding the url to them.

Comment: Then how can I use id="contact-form" in @using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: Just use the proper overload: `@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contact-form" }))`. See my answer.

Comment: Now the value is inserting to the database....Yeah I have noticed that also.... Its working.... ur great!!!

Comment: @raj2sekar1, if it is working and this answer helped you solve the problem you were having you should consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work